# Triple equal operator fails when checking for one of variants but they are the same type

Tags: php, if-statement, equality

```
$type = 'bravo';

if ($type === ('alpha' || 'bravo')) {
    echo $type;
}
```

This never returns anything. Why this is happening?

Comment: The subexpression `('alpha' || 'bravo')` evaluates to `True`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if ($type === 'alpha' || $type === 'bravo') {
    echo $type;
}
```

You have to check values individually.

Comment: Oh, okay, thank you.  I'm dumb.

Answer (score 1):

'alpha' || 'bravo' is boolean true not string 'bravo'